# Phonegap project: the database runs only with chrome

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, cordova

in the last days i've tried to realize an application with Phonegap in Javascript, HTML and CSS, but i have a problem...the application start when I run it from Google Chrome, but through another browser or android it doesn't. I've tried to resolve it but for me everything is ok. Can you help me please?

**FIRST PAGE**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
    * Create your own at http://cspisawesome.com
    -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" />
    <title>Viaggio Ideale</title>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 
    function onDeviceReady(){
     var db = window.openDatabase("ViaggioIdeale_DB", "1.0", "ViaggioIdeale", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB);
    }
 
    function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USA');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USA (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Nome TEXT NOT NULL, Clima TEXT NOT NULL, Interesse TEXT NOT NULL, Tipologia TEXT NOT NULL)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Alabama", "Mite", "Sport", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Alabama", "Mite", "Musica", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Alabama", "Mite", "Carnevale", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Alabama", "Mite", "Musei", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Alaska", "Rigido", "Ghiacciai", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Alaska", "Rigido", "Natura Estrema", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Arizona", "Arido", "Deserti", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Arizona", "Arido", "Canyon", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Arizona", "Arido", "Natura Estrema", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Arkansas", "Mite", "Musei", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Arkansas", "Mite", "Natura", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Arkansas", "Mite", "Fiumi", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("California", "Vario", "Natura Estrema", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("California", "Vario", "Grattacieli", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("California", "Vario", "Spiagge", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("California", "Vario", "Parchi Divertimento", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("California", "Vario", "Cucina", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("California", "Vario", "Deserti", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("California", "Vario", "Casinò", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("California", "Vario", "Cinema", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("California", "Vario", "Night Life", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Colorado", "Arido", "Natura Estrema", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Colorado", "Arido", "Canyon", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Colorado", "Arido", "Cucina", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Colorado", "Arido", "Deserti", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Connecticut", "Vario", "Musei", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Delaware", "Mite", "Musei", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Delaware", "Mite", "Natura", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Delaware", "Mite", "Estate", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Delaware", "Mite", "Festival", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Florida", "Vario", "Spiagge", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Florida", "Vario", "Grattacieli", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Florida", "Vario", "Parchi Divertimento", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Florida", "Vario", "Natura Estrema", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Florida", "Vario", "Night Life", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Georgia", "Arido", "Natura Estrema", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Hawaii", "Tropicale", "Natura Estrema", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Hawaii", "Tropicale", "Spiagge", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Hawaii", "Tropicale", "Natura Estrema", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Hawaii", "Tropicale", "Spiagge", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Hawaii", "Tropicale", "Natura Estrema", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Hawaii", "Tropicale", "Spiagge", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Hawaii", "Tropicale", "Mare", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Idaho", "Vario", "Natura Estrema", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Idaho", "Vario", "Parchi Divertimento", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Illinois", "Continentale", "Grattacieli", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Illinois", "Continentale", "Natura", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Illinois", "Continentale", "Musei", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Illinois", "Continentale", "Cucina", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Illinois", "Continentale", "Laghi", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Illinois", "Continentale", "Fiumi", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Illinois", "Continentale", "Night Life", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Illinois", "Continentale", "Parchi Divertimento", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Indiana", "Vario", "Grattacieli", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Indiana", "Vario", "Natura", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Indiana", "Vario", "Musei", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Indiana", "Vario", "Laghi", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Iowa", "Continentale", "Cucina", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Iowa", "Continentale", "Musei", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Kansas", "Vario", "Grattacieli", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Kansas", "Vario", "Musei", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Kansas", "Vario", "Fiumi", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Kansas", "Vario", "Natura", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Kentucky", "Mite", "Cucina", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Louisiana", "Sub-Tropicale", "Cucina", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Louisiana", "Sub-Tropicale", "Carnevale", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Louisiana", "Sub-Tropicale", "Musei", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Louisiana", "Sub-Tropicale", "Night Life", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Maine", "Vario", "Natura", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Maryland", "Sub-Tropicale", "Cucina", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Maryland", "Sub-Tropicale", "Musei", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Massachusetts", "Vario", "Grattacieli", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Massachusetts", "Vario", "Musei", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Massachusetts", "Vario", "Natura", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Massachusetts", "Vario", "Night Life", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Michigan", "Continentale", "Musei", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Michigan", "Continentale", "Natura", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Michigan", "Continentale", "Grattacieli", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Michigan", "Continentale", "Laghi", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Minnesota", "Continentale", "Musei", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Minnesota", "Continentale", "Laghi", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Minnesota", "Continentale", "Natura", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Mississipi", "Sub-Tropicale", "Fiumi", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Mississipi", "Sub-Tropicale", "Natura", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Missouri", "Continentale", "Fiumi", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Missouri", "Continentale", "Natura", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Missouri", "Continentale", "Grattacieli", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Montana", "Vario", "Natura Estrema", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Nebraska", "Vario", "Natura", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Nebraska", "Vario", "Musei", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Nevada", "Arido", "Deserti", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Nevada", "Arido", "Natura Estrema", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Nevada", "Arido", "Casinò", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Nevada", "Arido", "Grattacieli", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Nevada", "Arido", "Night Life", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("Nevada", "Arido", "UFO", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New Hampshire", "Vario", "Natura", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New Mexico", "Arido", "Deserti", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New Mexico", "Arido", "Natura Estrema", "Montagna")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New Mexico", "Arido", "Cucina", "Montagna")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New York", "Continentale", "Laghi", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New York", "Continentale", "Grattacieli", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New York", "Continentale", "Fiumi", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New York", "Continentale", "Night Life", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New York", "Continentale", "Cucina", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New York", "Continentale", "Casinò", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New York", "Continentale", "Musei", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New York", "Continentale", "Natura", "Mare")');

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New Jersey", "Vario", "Grattacieli", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New Jersey", "Vario", "Casinò", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New Jersey", "Vario", "Night Life", "Mare")');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USA(Nome,Clima,Interesse,Tipologia) VALUES ("New Jersey", "Vario", "Parchi Divertimento", "Mare")');
}
 
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Siamo spiacenti, c'è stato un errore di caricamento: "+err.code);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body><center><img style="margin-top:13%;" width="80%" src="img/logo.png">
        <br><br><br>
  <a href="mare.html"><button id="start" >Trova la tua nazione!</button></a><br><br>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/rizieri.mele"><button id="credits">Developer</button></a><br><br>
  <font size="1" color="white">Copyright Rizieri Mele - 2016</font>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

There are others pages, i add only others two (In the last page uploaded, the script doesn't work).

**SECOND PAGE**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
    * Create your own at http://cspisawesome.com
    -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" />
    <title>Mare</title>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 
 function salva(){
                var ris = document.getElementById("marmon");
    var tris = ris.options[ris.selectedIndex].text;
    localStorage.setItem("tipo",tris);
    
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
        <center>
  <div id="question"><h1><font face="Arial">Preferisci il Mare o la Montagna?</font></h1>
  <select id="marmon">
  <option>Mare</option>
  <option>Montagna</option>
</select><br><br><br>
  </div><br><br>
<a href="clima.html"><button onClick="salva()">Vai Avanti</button></a><br><br>
  <font size="1" color="white">Copyright Rizieri Mele - 2016</font>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

**THIRD PAGE**

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
    * Create your own at http://cspisawesome.com
    -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css" />
    <title>Clima</title>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/SQLitePlugin.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 
    function onDeviceReady(){
     var db = window.openDatabase("ViaggioIdeale_DB", "1.0", "ViaggioIdeale", 200000);
        db.transaction(queryDB);
    }
 
    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }
 
 function queryDB(tx){
             var tipo = localStorage.getItem("tipo");
                tx.executeSql('SELECT DISTINCT Clima FROM USA WHERE Tipologia = "'+tipo+'"',[],querySuccess,errorCB);
    }
  
  
 
    function querySuccess(tx,result){
        var len = result.rows.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                var riga = result.rows.item(i);
    document.getElementById('clima').innerHTML += '<option>'+riga["Clima"]+'</option>';
  }
  }
  
 function salva(){
                var ris = document.getElementById("clima");
    var tris = ris.options[ris.selectedIndex].text;
    localStorage.setItem("clima",tris);  
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
        <center>
  <div id="question"><h1><font face="Arial">Quale tipologia di clima preferisci?</font></h1>
  <select id="clima">
</select>
<br><br><br>
</div>
<br><br>
  
<a href="firstinteresse.html"><button onClick="salva()">Vai Avanti</a></button><br><br>
  <font size="1" color="white">Copyright Rizieri Mele - 2016</font>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

the absurd is that the script works in Google Chrome. I've tried to delete the data browser, thinking that can be these, but nothing.

PS: The database for each launch of application , it is eliminated and recreated , but it is a temporary thing , so I would to add an "IF" That controls if the application was started before or not.

Thank you very much to all!

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is not technology to use in browser, but it is for creating hybrid apps, so phonegap app works on builded in browser and uses native code to use native possibilities. I not understand what for you want to use it in browsers, maybe for testing, but any database or native methods will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use chrome for testing app (And database runs)...but after the building with Phonegap Build service...shows an error "Error processing query: Undefined" in the third page.